# Use Butterworth and Chebychev filters

Tags: reference-request, libraries, c++, signal-processing

I need to calculate frequency response, phase response and apply to signals the Butterworth, Chebychev1 and Chebychev2 band-pass filters.

I'm developing in C++ with Qt, and I'm looking for algorithms or a (free) library to do that. I have my plotting solution, I just need the formulas.

The input values I have are the time/amplitude signal, the order of the filter and the low and high cut-off frequencies.

Comment: Is this just a google question?

Comment: Nope, I searched and found nothing relevant (either not band-pass or implementations without algorithms provided)

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.kwon3d.com/theory/filtering/butt.html) gives formulas for butterworth and various common filters.

And here's [some C code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10498563/181638) to try.